# How to add a user to a channel in JDA?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am creating a Discord bot using JDA on the latest version and wanting to have channels created and when someone is mentioned in the channel, have them added so they can view the channel. Anyone know a way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow people to view a channel you have to create a permission override for that user.

```
public static void addUserToChannel(Channel channel, User user) {
    Guild guild = channel.getGuild();
    Member member = guild.getMember(user);
    channel.createPermissionOverride(member)
           .setAllow(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL)
           .queue();
}
```

This will create a permission override for the specific user and allow them to view the channel. To get users that were mentioned from a message you simply call [`message.getMentionedUsers()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/entities/Message.html#getMentionedUsers--).

If the user already has an override on the channel you must retrieve it through `channel.getPermissionOverride(member)` and modify it through the manager.

```
PermissionOverride override = channel.getPermissionOverride(member);
override.getManager().grant(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL).queue();
```

If there is no override present `getPermissionOverride(member)` will simply return `null`. You can use this to determine whether to **create** or **modify**.

---

This is done a little differently in JDA v4 where `Channel` has been renamed to `GuildChannel`.

In that version you can simply call `channel.upsertPermissionOverride(member).grant(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL).queue();` instead of using the manager.